# Kotlin issue with DayLight one Hours time difference

Tags: java, android, kotlin

converting UTC time and displays the Date and time in pacific format, where it works fine for normally, but when Daylight timing is used , shows one hour less

```
fun utcToGivenTimeZone(dateInUtc : String, timeZone : String) : String{
    var finalDateToReturn = ""
        try{
            val dateInUtc = dateInUtc
            val dateTimeAfterSplit = dateInUtc.split("T")?.get(0) + " " + (dateInUtc.split(
                  "T")?.get(1)?.split(".")?.get(0))

            val sourceFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            sourceFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
            val parsed = sourceFormat.parse(dateTimeAfterSplit)

            val tZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone)
            val destFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM yyyy @ hh:mm aa")
            destFormat.setTimeZone(tZone)
            val finalDate = destFormat.format(parsed)

            finalDateToReturn= finalDate.toString()

        } catch (e : Exception){
            Log.e("timezone",e.toString())
        }
    return finalDateToReturn
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example input and the actual as well as the expected output?

Comment: Sample input - Tue 04 Feb 2020 10:00:00 PDT

Actual output now - Tue 04 Feb 2020 @ 9:00 AM

Expected Out - Tue 04 Feb 2020 @ 10:00 AM

Comment: OK, thanks, but I don't understand why the input is trailed by `PDT` if it is considered to be in `UTC`... What time zone is `PDT`?

Comment: PDT Means Pacific Daylight Time

Comment: If `Tue 04 Feb 2020 10:00:00 PDT` is your input and `Tue 04 Feb 2020 @ 10:00 AM` is your desired output, where do you think does `UTC` come into play? Isn't the input the same time (and date)?